# SealedObject vs Stream Cypher, pros and cons

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have 2 way to encrypt and decrypt a java object:

a) using `SealedObject` and save and load this with normal `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream`

b) save the serialized object using `CipherOutputStream` and `CipherInputStream`

Are there differences in terms of performance and/or security between these two choices?

Answer (score -2):

`SealedObject:`

enables a programmer to create an object and protect its confidentiality with a cryptographic algorithm.

Given any Serializable object, one can create a SealedObject that encapsulates the original object, in serialized format (i.e., a "deep copy"), and seals (encrypts) its serialized contents, using a cryptographic algorithm such as DES, to protect its confidentiality. The encrypted content can later be decrypted (with the corresponding algorithm using the correct decryption key) and de-serialized, yielding the original object.

Note that the Cipher object must be fully initialized with the correct algorithm, key, padding scheme, etc., before being applied to a SealedObject.

`CipherInputStream:`

is composed of an InputStream and a Cipher so that read() methods return data that are read in from the underlying InputStream but have been additionally processed by the Cipher. The Cipher must be fully initialized before being used by a CipherInputStream.For example, if the Cipher is initialized for decryption, the CipherInputStream will attempt to read in data and decrypt them, before returning the decrypted data.This class adheres strictly to the semantics, especially the failure semantics, of its ancestor classes java.io.FilterInputStream and java.io.InputStream. This class has exactly those methods specified in its ancestor classes, and overrides them all. Moreover, this class catches all exceptions that are not thrown by its ancestor classes. In particular, the skip method skips, and the available method counts only data that have been processed by the encapsulated Cipher.It is crucial for a programmer using this class not to use methods that are not defined or overriden in this class (such as a new method or constructor that is later added to one of the super classes), because the design and implementation of those methods are unlikely to have considered security impact with regard to CipherInputStream.

`CipherOutPutStream:`

CipherOutputStream is composed of an OutputStream and a Cipher so that write() methods first process the data before writing them out to the underlying OutputStream. The cipher must be fully initialized before being used by a CipherOutputStream.For example, if the cipher is initialized for encryption, the CipherOutputStream will attempt to encrypt data before writing out the encrypted data.This class adheres strictly to the semantics, especially the failure semantics, of its ancestor classes java.io.OutputStream and java.io.FilterOutputStream. This class has exactly those methods specified in its ancestor classes, and overrides them all. Moreover, this class catches all exceptions that are not thrown by its ancestor classes.It is crucial for a programmer using this class not to use methods that are not defined or overriden in this class (such as a new method or constructor that is later added to one of the super classes), because the design and implementation of those methods are unlikely to have considered security impact with regard to CipherOutputStream.

You should have read the Oracle Documentation for this.

Comment: I have read Oracle documentation, but my question isn't what are SealedObject and CipherStreams, but *Are there differences in terms of performance?*

Comment: Everything is mentioned there if you need further deep knowledge Use `JavaDoc` they will give you more elaborate and JVM runtime environment knowledge i-e how they manipulate the things into objects and .obj files. Sorry if i have hurt you.

Comment: @NaveedYousaf He asked about difference and security of both approaches, now about thier functionality and your JavaDoc copypaste is completely unacceptable here